# Short-hand for return on true

Tags: c#, operator-keyword, conditional-operator, shorthand

I'm looking for a short-hand for return on true. The example code explains ii better:

```
if( error == true )
{
    return;
}
```

I'm asking about a short-hand version of the code above, basically something like:

```
error?return;
```

... or...

```
error?.return;
```

... or...

```
error||return;
```

... or whatever. You guys get the idea and, no, none of those work.

Thank you all.

Comment: And what would you get by reducing it to one line? Other than making it look more like bash and less like c#, lol...

Comment: It's get me hard to understand why people love to compare with true/false

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't get much simpler than a slight reduction on your own code.

Perhaps:

```
if( error) return;
```

Comment: also change the variable name error to something like "a" that will save you an astonishing 4 characters

Comment: (Also, I personally recommend using brackets {} otherwise you'll one day end up with: 

if( error) return;
   Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred");

Comment: Yep. I got that. The idea is to be able to hook up simple commands (not just a return) to a boolean flag on a single line. Easier to read, that's all, more sugar less syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator `?:` is not designed for control flow, it's only designed for conditional assignment. If you need to control the flow of your program, use a control structure, such as `if/else`.

the ternary operator is to initialize a variable with the result of the expression. At compile-time, the C# compiler translates the ternary expression into branch statements

`?.` is a new Null-Conditional Operator introduced in C#6.0

So the best approach would be

```
if(error) return
```

Comment: The conditional (aka ternary) operator is not going to work for same reason many of the OP's suggestions won't work, `return` is a statement, not an expression. It can't be used where an expression is expected (conditional operator, null-conditional operator, boolean operator, etc.).

Comment: I was hoping for something like `OnEventHandler?.Invoke(...)` which I find is more readable that null checking every event handler before use.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( error == true )
{
    return;
}
```

Assuming `error` is a boolean you can shorten it this way:

```
if (error) return;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Boolean returnvalue = error==true? true : false;
```

or

```
 Boolean returnvalue = error ? true : false;
```

Comment: Why do that instead of returning just error ? 

return error;

Comment: it will never return a blank value so you dont need to handle error for this, otherwise you have to set default value to false to your variable which is not good practice.